# Move row values to another row using a trigger in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a beginner in script google code. And now I have a problem with my code when I make a trigger in my spreadsheet. I have this code

```
function moveValuesOnly () {
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
          var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!B6:V9");
          var destRange = ss.getRange("Sheet1!B11:V14");
          var persamaan = ss.getRange("Sheet1!V6:V9")
          var nilai = ss.getRange("Sheet1!Z1").getValues
          // Déterminer l'emplacement de la première ligne vide.
          if(
          persamaan.getValues() == nilai
          )
          {
          source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
          source.clear ();
          }
        
        }
```

and I have this link for my spreadhseet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vhg8CRF1GWS9y300Bct3He1zm__hP9tCFGBOI86NiZs/edit?usp=sharing

In my spreadsheet I have range for B6 to V9. I want to make a trigger when the value of each V in V6 - V9 = 'Lulus' then check if B11 has a value so the B6 until V6 value copy in B12 but if B11 didn't have value so B6 until V6 value copy in B11.

Comment: (Please use a spelling checker. Capitalise the 1st person pronoun *I* everywhere, not just at the start of a sentence.)

Comment: but why another human can answer? but its okay its my mistake miss spell thank you

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not need a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) but an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetToWatch = 'Sheet1';
  const columnToWatch = 22; // column V
  const valueToWatch = 'Lulus';
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet');
  }
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.range
    || e.value !== valueToWatch
    || e.range.columnStart !== columnToWatch
    || e.range.rowStart <= sheet.getFrozenRows()
    || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch) {
    return;
  }
  const values = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues()
    .flat();
  sheet.appendRow(values);
  sheet.deleteRows(e.range.rowStart, 1);
}
```

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: when i edit the spreadsheet, the script didnt run.... why?

Comment: Chances are that the script runs fine. It will only do its thing when the value `Lulus` is hand entered in column `Sheet1!V`. To make it work on a sheet whose name is different from `Sheet1`, modify the line where `sheetToWatch` is defined.

Comment: i cannot run the script because it on edit

Comment: Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' line: 6 file: Code.gs

Comment: Your sample spreadsheet shows that you have modified line 6 of the code, introducing an error. Use the code given in the answer. Do not run the code in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you _hand edit_ the spreadsheet. It only moves the row where you enter `Lulus`in column V. Existing `Lulus` rows are not moved but only rows where you _enter_ `Lulus`.